# How does the Silverlight combobox disappear the way it does?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, combobox

In silverlight if I expand a combobox and then move the mouse cursor away, no matter where I click on the silverlight app the combobox dropdown collapses again. How does it do this and can I replicate it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Expression Blend, you can easily find out how it's done.

Simply create a SL project, add a `ComboBox` ot the surface, Right-Click it and select Edit Template->Make a Copy, then inspect the template, it's probably made with some animation on one of the transitions / Visual State Manager.

Comment: All due respect, but this is a bit of a non-answer/guess that should probably be a comment....

Comment: If the OP didn't know about and does have Blend I would definitely categorize this as answer.

Answer (score 2):

In Silverlight, this is done with states in the `VisualStateManager` (VSM for short).

[Silverlight Introduces the VSM](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/06/04/silverlight-introduces-visual-state-manager-vsm.aspx)

And here is template for ComboBox that you can use to see how it works with the VSM to make that happen and play around with it:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,25,2"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="comboToggleStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1F3B53"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#7FFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#CCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay2"/>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#E5FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#BCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#6BFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundOverlay3"/>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Highlight"/>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#E5FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#BCFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[2].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#6BFFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[3].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#F2FFFFFF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGradient2"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Background" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay" Fill="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay2" Fill="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundOverlay3" Fill="#FF448DCA" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient2" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FFFFFFFF" StrokeThickness="1">
                                                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint=".7,1" StartPoint=".7,0">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#F9FFFFFF" Offset="0.375"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#E5FFFFFF" Offset="0.625"/>
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#C6FFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    </Rectangle>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="Highlight" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" RadiusY="3.5" RadiusX="3.5" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Valid"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource comboToggleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z " HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="4" Margin="0,0,6,0" Stretch="Uniform" Width="8">
                                            <Path.Fill>
                                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BtnArrowColor" Color="#FF333333"/>
                                            </Path.Fill>
                                        </Path>
                                    </ToggleButton>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                        <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" Fill="White" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" RadiusY="3" RadiusX="3"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="1" Opacity="0" RadiusY="2" RadiusX="2" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            <Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement" BorderBrush="#FFDB000C" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Right" PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}">
                                        <ToolTip.Triggers>
                                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip">
                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                                    <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </EventTrigger>
                                        </ToolTip.Triggers>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="12" Margin="1,-4,-4,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="12">
                                    <Path Data="M 1,0 L6,0 A 2,2 90 0 1 8,2 L8,7 z" Fill="#FFDC000C" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                    <Path Data="M 0,0 L2,0 L 8,6 L8,8" Fill="#ffffff" Margin="1,3,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                                <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="1"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                                    </Border.Background>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: I've looked at that myself but it doesn't really help, I still don't see how the combobox can know when someone clicks away from it, or am I missing one of the visual states which actually does this?

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the control's template uses a Popup control, which you can use yourself in your own controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Funny enough - I've had this asked of me on an interview

Comment: Sorry my question may be a little bit vague, what I want to know is how the combobox knowst o make the popup box dissapear when you click away from it on something else (like another button or just dead space in the silverlight app).